# how to correct "located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My project solution does build without error but doesn't run any more :(

I tried to clean solution and project but didn't work.

This seems to occur after I installed some plugins for VS 2010 but I'm not sure.

Is there a way to solve this problem ?

Even a brand new project doesn't want to run anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can often happen as the result of some of the assembly's metadata changing. Has the version number been incremented? Alternatively this might happen if the private key used to sign the assembly has changed and the dependent code has not been recompiled to reflect the assembly's new identity.

There is also a possibility that some component of your project is targeting a different version of the .NET Framework or Common Language Runtime. The version number of the target framework is embedded in an assembly's metadata header and will affect assembly binding.

Another thought: it does sound like your VS2010 installation is busted. What happens if you try to compile from the command line outside of the IDE?

Comment: I'm beginner I don't know how to compile from cmdline so I uninstall  and reinstall everything. Thanks for help though.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problem when I previously opened a project developped in older version.
The solution is: close the project. Exit the program. Restart the program, load the project, compile and run.